# Ice pop recipe using egg yolks by two different ways

Tags: baking, ice-cream

A few days ago i started reading about popsicles recipes. Searching this out i found out about two sort of recipes using almost identical ingredients to make a creamy popsicle.

The first recipes uses:

sugar, egg yolks, milk, heavy cream

1) **Beat egg yolks and sugar until thicked and paled**. Then put the milk and heavy cream on medium heat (not to boil). Then add 1 cup of the milky mixture in the egg yolks mixture and whisk; then put this in the milky mixture to cook whisking all the time until is ready.

The second recipes uses:

sugar, egg yolks, milk, corn flour

2) Whisk off the heat sugar, milk and corn flour. Add the milk gradually and whisk until the ingredients are dissolved, **and then whisk in the egg yolks**. Cook until ready.

Why in the first recipe we beat the egg yolks with sugar and at the second recipe type we just whisk them in? I would like to know the logic behind this and which recipe is better for the final result.

Answer (score 5):

Because the recipe writers were used to those methods--seriously.

According to Harold McGee, in his *On Food and Cooking* (revised) beating eggs and sugar until they are pale--or even until they thicken--is only useful to indicate that the sugar is fully dissolved.  Otherwise, it makes little difference to the outcome of recipes.